# Adding a list to the task struct in sched.h

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to add a list to the task struct in sched.h in linux kernel (2.4.14-18).

I've added the member

```
list_t waitList
```

in the task_struct, and added

```
waitList:           LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.waitList)
```

to the INIT_TASK macro.

I get a kernel oops when i compile and load the kernel.
Is there anything else i need to do and missed?

Comment: Is that the actual line you added? It should be `.waitList = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.waitList),`

Comment: @StoryTeller I could add that to fork() i guess, but where can i put that line to initialize the list of the first process?

the line i put is the same as initialization for say "run_list" that is also a member of task

Comment: `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is a macro. The above will expand to `.waitList = {&(tsk.waitList), &(tsk.waitList)},` And it belongs in `INIT_TASK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i added the new member in the middle of the struct, which messed up initializing the init process.

Moving it to the end of the task struct solved the problem.